# Flask button click run a .PY file

Tags: python, ajax, flask, raspberry-pi, webserver

just to note security isnt an issue as it is on a closed network and only i can access the PI.

I am trying to have a webpage with buttons on it to run my
USB.py file and USB2.py file etc.

so I have installed flask and got the webpage up and was using this html to load USB.py

I think I am having a problem with it not being able to find the file USB.py. I have put the file in the same as the flask also tried putting it in templates. I have tried putting in the line /home/joe/USB.py where the file is located but it still errors.
I was going to put it in the root but seems a bit wrong.
the error i get when i click the button on the server is "GET /USB.py HTTP/1/1" 404

Im not a programmer so please dont get to complex with answers :)

the flask file is standard

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
  return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run(debug=True, port=80, host='0.0.0.0')
```

the HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>    
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="button" id='script' name="scriptbutton" value=" Run Script " onclick="goPython()">

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script>
        function goPython(){
            $.ajax({
              url: "USB.py",
             context: document.body
            }).done(function() {
             alert('finished python script');;
            });
        }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your USB.py file is not your Flask app, but a separate application you want to run based on a front end trigger.

Your ajax request does not run USB.py as you may think it does. If it could, that'd be a horrible security hole. A random, untrusted client being able to execute an arbitrary script on the server would mean the whole internet breaks, without exaggeration.

The typical way to run an application on the server is to expose a route that runs the application on behalf of the client, in a secure way.

For example,

USB1.py:

```py
print("hello world")
```

app.py:

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template
from subprocess import check_output


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.get("/run")
def run():
    return check_output(["python3", "USB1.py"])


@app.get("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

templates/index.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<button>Run Script</button>
<script>
$("button").click(() => {
  $.ajax({url: "run"})
    .done(data => {
      alert(data);
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

You can extend this to pass query parameters to the route which are then passed to your script, but be careful with that to avoid allowing remote code execution. You can return JSON back to the client containing more interesting data as well.

Now, the above approach is [a little weird](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676/399876): we're running `python3` as a subprocess from `python3`! Depending on what USB1.py does, the normal way would be to import it as a module and invoke a function, all in the same process. Less overhead, safer and cleaner.

USB1.py:

```py
def greet():
    return "hello world"
```

app.py:

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template
from USB1 import greet


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.get("/run")
def run():
    return greet()


@app.get("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Same client and result.

As an aside, you might want to serve index.html as a plain static file if there's nothing dynamic happening in the template.